# How to properly generate an xml from xquery

Tags: xquery

I'm new to xquery and is trying to read different references on using the tool. I've been trying to play around testing and trying to generate some xml format messages but this one puzzles me. Here's my xQuery code:

**Sample XQuery**

```
declare variable $requestBody as element() external;
declare function VerifyOrderDetailTransformation($requestBody as element())
as element() {
    <msg>
        <header>
            <headtitle>This is the title</headtitle>
        </header>
        <dbody>
            {GenerateEquipmentListNodes($requestBody)} 
        </dbody>
    </msg>
};

declare function GenerateEquipmentListNodes($requestBody as element())
as element()* {

    let $titleList := (
        for $e in $requestBody//bookstore//book
            let $dTitle := $e/title/text()
            return 
               <theTitle>{$dTitle}</theTitle>
        )

    return 
       <dTitleList>
           {$titleList}
       </dTitleList>
};

VerifyOrderDetailTransformation($requestBody)
```

**Sample XML**

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

And here's the output generated by running xQuery on the XML:

**Current output**

```
<msg> 
    <head> 
        <title>This is the title</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <dTitleList/> 
    </body> 
</msg>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<msg> 
    <head> 
        <title>This is the title</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <dTitleList> 
        <theTitle>Everyday Italian</theTitle>
        <theTitle>Harry Potter</theTitle>
        <theTitle>XQuery Kick Start</theTitle>
        <theTitle>Learning XML</theTitle>
        <dTitleList/> 
    </body> 
</msg>
```

---

My question is, what could I have probably missed?

Comment: Seems your `$titeList` is empty.

Comment: I think Ranon is right. Perhaps try $requestBody//book instead of $requestBody//bookstore//book.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for helping me out, that did it :) And also thanks for the reminder about the namespace. Great job.

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with your input: You're querying this XML:

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <!-- snip -->
  </book>
  <!-- snip -->
</bookstore>
```

The first part of your XPath query, namely `$queryBody//bookstore`, looks for all descendant elements which have an element `<bookstore/>` below - what return an empty result. `$queryBody//bookstore` won't do either, as the context already is on the `<bookstore/>` element.

For this reason, ommit `//bookstore`, so your this should be `$queryBody//book`.

Use this function with the changed XPath in it:

```
declare function local:GenerateEquipmentListNodes($requestBody as element())
as element()* {

    let $titleList := (
        for $e in $requestBody//book
            let $dTitle := $e/title/text()
            return 
               <theTitle>{$dTitle}</theTitle>
        )

    return 
       <dTitleList>
           {$titleList}
       </dTitleList>
};
```

---

One more remark: You should put your own functions into `local:` function namespace or define your own one. Using the default namespace is discouraged and not compatible with all processors. I changed it to the `local:`-namespace.

Comment: I think you are quite close. The Sample XML shown by Elmer shows no wrapper, but the code is such that you have to pass in the root element instead of the root node, e.g. the document node. That causes $requestBody//bookstore to no longer work. One could also make that expression more failsafe by using $requestBody/descendant-or-self::bookstore, which is subtle different from the original expression.

Comment: Aye, was to puzzled with getting the code running without external variables to register that. ;) Probably you should post that as an answer or update mine...

Comment: It was your hint that inspired me, so go ahead and take the credit. ;-)